# Namespaced key lookup on Rails 5 association with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Supervision::ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.abstract_class = true

   def self.table_name_prefix
     "supervision_"
   end
end
---------------
class Supervision::Activity < Supervision::ApplicationRecord
  has_one :supervision_missed_visit, class_name: Supervision::MissedVisit
  (...)
end
---------------
class Supervision::MissedVisit < Supervision::ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :supervision_activity, class_name: Supervision::Activity
  (...)
end
```

And I also have this model, which isn't namespaced:

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  (...)
end
```

Whenever I try to reach the `Supervision::MissedVisit` through its `has_one` relationship, as in

`@supervision_activity.supervision_missed_visit`

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column supervision_missed_visits.activity_id does not exist
```

How do I make it so that Rails understands that I'm actually looking for `supervision_missed_visits.supervision_activity_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the foreign key:

`has_one :supervision_missed_visit, class_name: Supervision::MissedVisit, foreign_key: 'supervision_activity_id'`

Another way to do it would be to create an instance method in `Supervision::Activity`:

```
def missed_visit
  Supervision::MissedVisit.where(supervision_activity_id: id).take
end
```